# How to represent an unknown number of layers in data with Django models

Tags: python, django, database, relational-database

How is the following data structure best represented in a set of Django database models:

```
Top level element
  An unknown number n of Mid level element(s), n >= 1
    Low level element
```

For example:

```
Top
  Mid
    Mid
      Mid
        Bottom
```

or

```
Top
  Mid
    Bottom
```

The issue is that the model for the Mid-level element cannot have both a Mid-level element and a Top-level element as parents.  The solutions I can think of are:

### Two foreign keys in the Mid-level model

The mid-level model can have a foreign key relationship with `Top` and another one with `'self'`.  This seems hacky because if you want to move down through the layers, you have to check both keys at each layer - when you know that only the first `Mid` has a relationship with `Top`, while everything else has a relationship with `Mid`.

```
class Mid(models.Model):
    top_parent = models.ForeignKey(Top, blank=True, null=True)
    mid_parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

### Make Top an instance of Mid instead

Eliminate `Top` altogether so that `Mid`s always link to other `Mid`s.  The issue with this solution is that `Top` has some unique properties that I don't want to add to `Mid` if it can be avoided.

### Use generic relations

Use generic relations so that `Mid` can link to both `Top` and `Mid`.  The downside is that this adds a lot of complexity to the code.

Here's a related question I found a bit later:
[Django: How do I model a tree of heterogeneous data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291249/django-how-do-i-model-a-tree-of-heterogeneous-data-types/1837041#1837041)

Comment: Could you please explain why the answer is not accurate? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be: **make Top a proxy model of Mid**.

```
class Mid(models.Model):
    mid_parent = models.ForeignKey('self')

class Top(Mid):
    # here you have your unique properties
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

As the `mid_parent` field is required, the `Top` instance could have itself as `mid_parent`.